# How to remove protection from a table cell?

Tags: macos, office-for-mac, microsoft-word-2011

I have an old Word 2007 file, which I already worked on for a while using Word 2011. Unfortunately I ran into the issue of a locked cell, which I cannot edit nor remove. Even the `Edit / Cut` functionality is deactivated once this cell is part of the selection.

It contains only a pull down menu, which is rendered without pull down functionality (it's not possible to select a different value).

The document is not protected. I already tried the `Tools / Protect Document` then `Tools / Unprotect Document` without any success.

How can I remove this 'protection'?

Comment: It seems to be a bug in Word 2011: the menu works correctly in Word 2011 and the value can be easily changed

Answer (score 3):

Open the Word document from which you want to remove protection.

Go to the "Review" tab of the ribbon.

Click the "Restrict Editing" button in the "Protect" group. The "Restrict Formatting and Editing" task pane will open.

Click the "Stop Protection" button at the bottom of the task pane. Enter the document password. Click "OK."

Save the changes to the document by clicking the "Save" button on the "Quick Access Toolbar" or using the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl+S."

Answer (score 0):

Save as your document with word 2003 doc format. It'll ask to remove content protection approve it. Then it'll be editable. The you can save as new word format and continue with that.